# Understanding voltage terms

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, function-generator

i am using a voltage divider circuit and i provide input using a function generator. For example I give a 1 Vpp square wave. Now, I measure the voltage across the resistors using multimeter and calculate the voltage at  different outputs (1-8) . I have attached the image of the circuit for reference.[image: voltage divider]

my question : The calculated voltage at the outputs are what type of volatages (Is it peak voltage or Peak to peak )

Comment: That depends on your measurement device. Does it measure peak voltage or peak to peak voltage? Multimeter usually do neither.

Comment: It might measure RMS or, it might measure DC average (depending on your settings)

Comment: Less of a detail, but if you *at least* for future posts can orient pictures right way.

Comment: The multimeter I use is a Autoranging digital multimeter (RS PRO RS 14 ) . Have any idea what voltage it measures?

Comment: @Dharani It will measure *something*. In DC mode, it might measure an averaged value if the square wave's fundamental frequency is sufficiently higher than the internal bandwidth, or something more like peak voltage, if it does a maximum hold. Or it might actually display an overly high value due to overshoot. Or it might show something that is a bit lower than the root mean square. If the manual doesn't specify what the meter does with square waves, neither can we. Multimeters aren't built for square waves. They're built for DC and sinusoidal AC.

Comment: @Dharani but **none of that has anything to do with your voltage divider**. It just means you're trying to use a measurement device that you haven't understood for a signal that it's not built to measure accurately.